# Using Intents with Google Calendar in Android - Workarounds for the existing bug?

Tags: android, android-intent, outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm creating an Android application. In this application I need to schedule appointment, and for this I'm creating calendar events. For this, I try to follow the guidelines provided in the CalendarContract guidelines (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

For manage the events that I create (or event to create a new ones), I want to use the official approach, so I don't depend of the Calendar App installed (Google, Outlook, another). So I follow the guidelines in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-edit 
I'm facing problems, and searching, I see that the peoples knows that Google Calendar doesn't follow their own Google guides. I need a suggestion for better workaround these issues, with the constraint that my code has to work with other Calendar Apps too (if the user uses Outlook, e.g., instead Google my App has to continue running.

```
{
private static void StartContentCalendarActivity(@Nullable Fragment fragment,
                                                 @NotNull String action,
                                                 @Nullable CalEvent event,
                                                 @Nullable ConContact contact,
                                                 @Nullable CalEventType type,
                                                 boolean isInvited) {
    Intent intent;
    int requestCode;

    if (!(fragment == null || fragment.isDetached() || fragment.isRemoving())) {
        intent = new Intent();
        requestCode = buildContentCalendarIntent(intent, action, event, contact, type, isInvited);
        // TODO: Add animation
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Activity is invalid when launching create agenda event");
    }
}   
private static int buildContentCalendarIntent(Intent intent,
                                                  @NotNull String action,
                                                  @Nullable CalEvent event,
                                                  @Nullable ConContact contact,
                                                  @Nullable CalEventType type,
                                                  boolean isInvited) {
        int requestCode;
        Uri calendarUri;
        String customAppPackage;
        String customAppUri;
        String title;
        ConPostal postal;
        ConPhone phone;

        requestCode = REQUEST_UNKNOWN;
        intent.setAction(action);
        calendarUri = event != null ? event.getUri() : CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
        intent.setDataAndType(calendarUri, "vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);

        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT:
            case Intent.ACTION_INSERT:
                customAppPackage = App.getPackage();
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, customAppPackage);
                customAppUri = CalEvent.buildCustomAppUri(contact, type, false);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI,customAppUri);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_CUSTOM_APP_URI, customAppUri);
                title = Resources.getString(R.string.cus_event_title,
                                type.getLabel(),
                                contact != null ? contact.getName() : "");
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
                if (contact != null) {
                    if (type == CalEventType.Visit) {
                        postal = contact.getPostal();
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
                                        postal != null ? postal.getFormatted() : "");
                    }
                    if (type == CalEventType.Call) {
                        phone=contact.getPhone();
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
                                        phone!=null ? phone.getNormalized() : "");
                    }
                }
                if (contact != null && isInvited) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, contact.getEMailsAsArray());
                }
                requestCode = REQUEST_CONTENTCALENDAR_INSERT;
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_EDIT:
                requestCode = REQUEST_CONTENTCALENDAR_EDIT;
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_VIEW:
                requestCode = REQUEST_CONTENTCALENDAR_VIEW;
                break;
            default:
                // Nothing
        }
        return requestCode;
    }
```

}

These are the approaches I'm testing, and the problems I'm facing:

1. Using ACTION_INSERT to create the event

   - When the event is created, the Activity doesn't return to my App (method onActivityResult), and I'm not able to get the URI of the recently created event
   - I'm not able to set the fields (required for my app) CUSTOM_APP_URI and CUSTOM_PACKAGE (neither with EXTRA_CUSTOM_APP_URI or Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI)
2. Using ACTION_EDIT to edit a previously added event

   - Instead of editing the previously created event, Google Calendar shows an empty one to create it. Event worse than edit, it does not read the Extras
3. Using ACTION_VIEW to view the event, and the user can edit manually. This almost works, but I need that the event return to my App
4. Using ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT: Is not recognized as a valid intent for Calendar uris

Comment: did you find any solutions? I am facing similar issue; cannot set CUSTOM_APP_URI and CUSTOM_PACKAGE

Comment: Not yet, and it's really annoying!